# 60A sub panel located 220' from source...in conduit..what guage al wire to meet ONT Elec code?

Tags: subpanel, wire

I want to wire a 60A subpanel that is 220' from the main source. The wire will be AL and run through a buried conduit.... Must meet Ontario Electrical code

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, questions on local code are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about local code.

Comment: How much amp loading do you *actually* expect to see on a regular basis? Daily peaks, not extraordinary peaks?

Comment: I have 2 RV's that are plugged in to 30A receptacles…. Not expecting both to run AC at the same time but one could add a base load to any other equipment operating in the shop